# Contents of INST not getting installed during R package install

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava, r-package

I am having trouble getting the contents of my INST folder to copy over to the root folder of the package (or copy over in general)

My R package depends on two java packages and their jars, these are both included as follows:

```
PackageTest
+-- inst
|   +-- impala-jdbc-cdh5
    |    +-- *.jar
|   +-- sqlserver-jdbc-4
    |    +-- *.jar
+-- R
|   +-- hello.R
+-- man
|   +-- hello.Rd
+-- DESCRIPTION  
+-- NAMESPACE
+-- .Rbuildignore
```

From my understanding the contents of the Package/inst folder should be moved to the root of the folder on install resulting in a folder structure that looks like this:

```
PackageTest
+-- impala-jdbc-cdh5
|    +-- *.jar
+-- sqlserver-jdbc-4
    +-- *.jar
+-- R
|   +-- PackageTest
|   +-- PackageTest.rdb
|   +-- PackageTest.rdx
+-- Meta
+-- html
+-- help
+-- DESCRIPTION  
+-- NAMESPACE
+-- INDEX
```

Instead I am missing the two folders listed at the top:

```
PackageTest
+-- R
|   +-- PackageTest
|   +-- PackageTest.rdb
|   +-- PackageTest.rdx
+-- Meta
+-- html
+-- help
+-- DESCRIPTION  
+-- NAMESPACE
+-- INDEX
```

There are other files in the other folders, but nothing that I am concerned with.

**What I have tried:**

I am using RStudio to generate this package and all I am doing is modifying the DESCRIPTION package to include the two Java packages. (so it really is a stub package with some Java jars - I have also imported rJava)

To build and install the package I have tried using `devtools::build` and `devtools:install` and the shortcuts that RStudio provides (Ctrl + Shift + B).

I have also tried to upload this repo onto our internal Git repo and use `devtools::install_git` and that results in the same issue.

Restructuring the `inst` folder to so that all the jars are in `inst/Java` has not helped with my issue.

Lastly, the package we have deployed on our production repo is bundled the exact same as the first example and we have no issues using the impala and sql drivers.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT:

`.Rbuildignore`

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
```

Comment: Anything relevant in your `.Rbuildignore` ? Also, can you get the contents of `inst` to install correctly in a toy package? If so, maybe proceed by building your way up to a package more and more like your actual package, adding jar files, changing file and directory names, and so forth, to learn which piece of your actual package is triggering the failure.

Comment: I can't even get the the test package to install the contents of `inst`. I have edited the post to include the contents of my `.Rbuildignore